# How to create slow frame rate video from image sequence?

Tags: encoding

I made a set of timelapse .jpg images using a Canon Rebel camera & Magic Lantern. I want to turn it into an .mp4 video.

I understand that Quicktime v10.5 can do this, but the slowest frame rate is about 24 frames per second. I want frame rates of only 6 or even 2 frames per second. I used to use Quicktime v7 but it will not run on Catalina anymore.

What Catalina software will create a 2 frames/sec video from an image sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Another unsatisfying (and potentially disk-intensive), but quick solution is to go to the directory, select all the images you want to use, then right-click and duplicate 3 times (for 6 frames/sec) or 11 times (for 2 frames/sec) -- that is, make 4 or 12 copies of each image. The "duplicate" command will give them names that should keep everything in order in QuickTime without having to rename anything. Then the 24 fps setting should give an equivalent of 6 or 2 fps.

Answer (score 0):

A rather unsatisfying, but workable, solution, suggested on another forum is to use [iMovie](https://www.apple.com/imovie/). The work around is to create a movie with the jpegs, essentially setting them as a sequence of stills. Then go to iMovie preferences,

- Set "Photo placement" to Fit (the default is Ken Burns)
- change the "Photo duration" of stills to a fraction of a second, say .2/frames per second
- AND reduce the "Transition" to 0.0

Finally File > Share > File
to export it as an .mp4 file.

All this because some Apple software engineer didn't want to bother allowing the frame rate on a Quicktime v10 export to be settable to any number. And we cannot have discussions like this on the Apple Support site because it is bad marketing.
Which is Why software versions peak and then degrade over time!!

i am hoping there is an open source or useful video editing app that is comparable to the old Quicktime 7 editing capacity. Please post it here if you know one.